# git add/rm (committing)

Tags: git

So I've taken over a website, some of which has been under git version control (one of the devs used it, the other didn't). So I'm going to commit everything so far, and work from there.

However, there are a few files with a git status which I don't quite understand. They are labelled as:

```
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

So if I simply run git commit, will the changes made to these files work their way in to the repository? It's just I don't get why you would do add/rm- seems like adding and then removing all in one foul swoop.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: file "changed but not updated"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812096/git-file-changed-but-not-updated)

Comment: The tip is not suggesting that you should both add and rm them. It's saying those are two commands which might do what you want. (Also I think you've got an old version of Git - in more recent versions it will say "Changes to be committed" or "Changes not staged for commit", and rm is not part of the hints.)

Comment: In addition to upgrading Git, given the kinds of questions you're asking, you might want to read through some more documentation, e.g. [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are staged but not committed.  Yes, if you simply run git commit, they will be committed.  More to the point, do you want to commit these files?  They may or may not be the same as your working files.  http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/18/the-staging-area.html is a decent introduction to the staging area.

Comment: Thanks, so is what git is ready to commit (potentially) different from what is in the working copy?

Comment: Yes.  The staging area is "what I'm about to commit".  This allows you to commit only portions of changed files, to verify your commit is as you want, etc.  Though it's one of the more "there is no spoon" concepts in git, it's also one of the more powerful ones.

Comment: Cool. So is there a way to diff between the staging area and the working copy?

Comment: @penguin: Yes, `git diff`. To diff between current commit and working copy, `git diff HEAD`, and to diff between current commit and index (staging area), `git diff --cached`. (See `man git-diff`.)

Answer (score 10):

Usually, if you want to take things as they are in the working folder you would

```
git add -A
```

which would stage all changes including the act of deleting a file and of tracking files that were not tracked yet.

It is wise to review your `.gitignore` file before doing this so you don't commit unwanted artifacts which can bloat your repository and pollute the output of diffs and patches.

Once you have done this you can

```
git commit
```

to record the changes in history. Then you can

```
git push origin your_branch_name
```

to share this new history with the remote you set up.